# Google Maps Print - Strange Empty Block

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This seems like such a silly problem, but it has me baffled...
I have broken my page down into the simplest elements and the problem is still occurring.

I have a page with a google map inside a div. When printing the map, there is a small section towards the bottom that prints empty. I have absolutely no idea how to rectify this.

The issue is already evident in the print preview.
Here is a screen shot: http://tinypic.com/r/e7xqb9/8

The page is intended to print on an A4 page and is designed to fit the page with no resizing neccessary.

This seems to be happening across Chrome, IE, Firefox and Safari browsers.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated !!

```
<html>
<body>            
<form id="form1">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:620px;height:620px;"></div>
            </form>


            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>


            <script>

                // Variable Declarations
                var map;

                // function initializes Google map
                function initialize() {

                    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.732393, 24.125977); //Google map Coordinates

                    var googleMapOptions =
                    {
                        center: mapCenter, // map center
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                        streetViewControl: false,
                        zoomControl: false,
                        panControl: false,
                        mapTypeControl: false,
                        zoom: 5
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), googleMapOptions);

                }

        initialize();



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is probably an issue with the size of the map div.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any HTML/CSS required to replicate the issue.

Comment: as I said in my question, the size I have chosen will perfectly fix on an A4 sheet of paper. In addition, the code above that I supplied is 100% complete and usable.

Comment: There is no size being defined in the code posted, A4 or otherwise.  How can I replicate the issue?  As a guess, your browser doesn't agree with you that the size fits the page "perfectly".

Comment: the width and height are defined in the style attribute of the div...

Comment: Is there any HTML above the posted code (or below it for that matter), there is no `<html>` tag posted (and the `</html></body>` wasn't displaying)

Comment: The BODY and HTML tags were the only tags removed by StackOverflow's code elements. I have put together this JSFiddle for you, but the results differ as they are using frames - which I am not. http://jsfiddle.net/kf208mgn/

Comment: I have updated the code above to include the BODY and HTML tags

Comment: The issue described does **not** happen with the code you provided.

Comment: it does indeed if you take the code into a blank HTML page. As I mentioned, the JSFiddle one does not - but they are using frames...

Comment: It does **NOT** happen. You should try to read and understand what others tell you in their comments. Check your CSS. I hardly believe this **is** your complete code. Why is your map in a `<form>` element? Is anything applied to that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing your code again it actually happens **when trying to print in landscape mode only** which you did not mention in your question.

Solution: adapt the `height` of your map container so that it fits onto A4 paper in landscape mode.